# C++ Delete Operator

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm relatively new to C++ and I have an issue which I really do not understand. My code creates a linked list. It is actually longer than this, but I chopped it down for the purpose of this question.

When I run the code, it adds three nodes and then when it goes to delete the node with the URI `b`, it calls the `delete` operator and ends up deleting the node, but then it seems to go back to `delete` operator (when I step through it) and it kills my whole list.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;


class CLinkedList
{
protected:
    class ip_uri_store
    {
    public:
        string uri, ip;
        ip_uri_store* next;

        ip_uri_store(const string& URI, const string& IP) {uri = URI, ip = IP, next = NULL;}
    };
    typedef ip_uri_store* nodeAddress;

    nodeAddress head;

    void AddNode(const string&, const string&, nodeAddress);
    void DeleteNode(const string&, nodeAddress, nodeAddress);

public:
    CLinkedList() {head = NULL;}
    void AddNode(const string& URI, const string& IP) {AddNode(URI, IP, head);}
    void DeleteNode(const string& URI) {DeleteNode(URI, head, head);}

};

void CLinkedList::AddNode(const string& URI, const string& IP, nodeAddress node)
{
    nodeAddress temp = new ip_uri_store(URI, IP);
    temp->uri = URI;
    temp->ip = IP;
    temp->next = head;
    head = temp;
}

void CLinkedList::DeleteNode(const string& URI, nodeAddress node, nodeAddress behindNode)
{
    if(node)
    {
        if(!node->uri.compare(URI))
            node == head ? head = head->next : behindNode->next = node->next;
        else
            DeleteNode(URI, node->next, node);

        delete node;
    }
}



int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    CLinkedList lList;
    lList.AddNode("a", "1");
    lList.AddNode("b", "2");
    lList.AddNode("c", "3");
    lList.DeleteNode("b");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That is serious abuse of the ternary conditional operator.

Comment: Considering he's new to this, the code seems copied from a random site...

Comment: I didn't copy it.  It's my code.  By new I mean a few months.  I've been reading a lot about c++...

Comment: Is it just me or are linked list implementations hard to read?

Comment: "Basically, what happens is, " is pretty superfluous.

Comment: What does "it kills my whole list" mean? That's the only detail you've given us about your problem.

Comment: @KerrekSB  Could you please elaborate on your comment?

Comment: @user968243: Just use an ordinary `if (node == head) { ... } else { ... }` construction. The ternary conditional is for use inside expressions, like `const int & a = condition ? x : y;`; it is *not* just an alternative to an `if` block. If you don't know comfortably what `c ? a : b = d;` really means, then don't use the ternary operator.

Answer (score 3):

You are calling `delete node;` even if the comparison fails (i.e. `node->uri != URI`).

```
if(!node->uri.compare(URI))
{
    node == head ? head = head->next : behindNode->next = node->next;
    delete node;
}
else
    DeleteNode(URI, node->next, node);
```

Also, the condition seems to be inverted.

Comment: Thank you very much.  The recursion confused me.  I did not realise that it called DeleteNode in the else part, ran the delete, and the re-called it when it returned to the the calling function.  Thanks again!

Comment: Nothing gets "re-called". Recursion isn't magic: you're just performing a function call, like any other. Execution continues when the function call is complete.

Comment: @user968243, you should try to rewrite this without recursion. As a general rule of thumb, you should only use recursion on trees for which you can guarantee limited height. Try to check the URI and if the comparison fails, assign `node` to its successor and repeat (with a loop construct like `while`).

Answer (score 1):

First, you should use std::list and avoid reinventing the world.
Anyway, if you are stuck to this implementation for some reason :

- temp->uri = URI; and temp->ip = IP; in the AddNode method are useless because the members are already initialized in the constructor of ip_uri_store class.
- the deletion of the head of the list occurs because the 'delete node' should only be done in the case node->uri.compare(URI) in the DeleteNode method.

Again, you should seriously consider using standard classes...

Comment: I do know about std::List; however, I have to implement a linked list using classes and recursion.  In the future though, I shall use std::List.  Thank you for point out the unnecessary assignement.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling delete on all the nodes. It needs to be moved inside the conditional so you only delete the nodes that match the URI

```
if(!node->uri.compare(URI)) {
    node == head ? head = head->next : behindNode->next = node->next;
    delete node;
} else {
    DeleteNode(URI, node->next, node);
}
```